# What is the ember.js idiomatic way to create static variables in model?

Tags: ember.js

This is the way I've figured out how to do, using reopenClass, but it's quite ugly. I really think that there is a better way to do that.

(Coffee Script)

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend
  text: DS.attr('string')
  state: DS.attr('string')

App.Post.reopenClass
  STATES_ARRAY: ['published', 
                 'delayed', 
                 'approved' ]
```

Thanks in advance, Gustavo

Comment: That's how it's supposed to be done.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with what you posted. You might have a look at `EnumeratedTransform` in this pull request: https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/505/files